# Non-parser example for `Control.Applicative.optional`

Tags: haskell, alternative-functor

I've recently stumbled over the generic [`Control.Applicative.optional`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v%3aoptional) combinator:

```
optional :: Alternative f => f a -> f (Maybe a)
optional v = Just <$> v <|> pure Nothing
```

but I don't much practical use for that combinator; e.g. when applied to pure functors such as lists or `Maybe`, the results don't seem very useful:

```
> optional [1,2,3]
[Just 1,Just 2,Just 3,Nothing]

> optional Nothing
Just Nothing

> optional (Just 1)
Just (Just 1)
```

...what would be more sensible applications of [`optional`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v%3aoptional)?

Comment: Well, parsers spring to mind :)

Comment: There was a long discussion on the Cafe recently about `some` and `many` which have the same use cases as `optional`, i.e. parsers and "things that may fail" ... http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-December/097476.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is useful for modelling any computation that is allowed to fail.

For example, let's say that you are dealing with STM and have these functions:

```
-- A database of Ints stored in a TVar
intDatabase :: TVar (ComplexDatabaseStructure Int)

-- Inserts an Int in the int database.
insertInt :: Int -> STM ()

-- Organizes the DB so that it is more efficient
optimizeDb :: STM ()

-- Checks whether an Int is in the DB
lookupInt :: Int -> STM Bool
```

Now, optimization is nice to do after inserts, but it isn't critical. So you could see this usage:

```
insert2AndCheck1 a b c =
  insertInt a *> insertInt b *> optional optimizeDb *> lookupInt c
```

This function inserts two ints, then *tries* to optimize the DB, but if it fails (because of STM reasons, like that someone was inserting something at the time), it isn't a big deal; we just go on anyways.

`optional` works with STM, and also any error monad in `Control.Monad.Error`, and a lot of different things; certainly also for pure computations.